# convert mongodb schems to prisma schema

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, prisma

i have a nexjs project which use mongodb and mongoose.
i want to convert mongodb schema to prisma schema.
i know how to convert most part of my code but in this code i dont know how convert {type:[ExtraPriceSchema]} part to prisma schema.

```
import mongoose, {model, models, Schema} from "mongoose";

const ExtraPriceSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  price: Number,
});

const MenuItemSchema = new Schema({
  image: {type: String},
  name: {type: String},
  description: {type: String},
  category: {type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId},
  basePrice: {type: Number},
  sizes: {type:[ExtraPriceSchema]},
  extraIngredientPrices: {type:[ExtraPriceSchema]},
}, {timestamps: true});

export const MenuItem = models?.MenuItem || model('MenuItem', MenuItemSchema);
```

this is my convert schima :

```
model category {
  id                        String   @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  name                      String   @unique
  timestamps                DateTime 
}

model MenuItem {
  id                        String   @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  name                      String?
  image                     String? 
  description               String?  
  category                  category[]
  basePrice                 Int?
  sizes                     ExtraPriceSchema
  extraIngredientPrices     ExtraPriceSchema
  timestamps                DateTime 
}

model ExtraPriceSchema {
  name  String?
  price Int?
}
```

app show error in fields of 'sizes' and 'extraIngredientPrices'.
the problem is i dont know how should I set @relation betwinn connect 'sizes' and 'extraIngredientPrices' and ExtraPriceSchema?